# Prisma deploy: relations are expected for enums/expecting an interface, directive or definition

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm trying to deploy my updated `datamodel.prisma` file. However, an error occurs and from what I can understand, it thinks that I'm trying to create a relation between an enum I defined above with the User type.

Here is my file:

```
enum Permission {
  ADMIN
  USER
  ITEMCREATE
  ITEMUPDATE
  ITEMDELETE
  PERMISSIONUPDATE
}

type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  resetToken: String
  resetTokenExpiry: String
  permissions: [Permission]
}

type Item {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  description: String!
  image: String
  largeImage: String
  price: Int!
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}
```

Running `prisma deploy --env-file variables.env` gives me this error below:

```
Errors:

  User
    ✖ Valid values for the strategy argument of `@scalarList` are: RELATION.
```

If I change `permissions: [Permission]` to `permissions: Permission[]`, it gives this error instead (specifically, `expected ImplementsInterfaces, DirectivesConst or FieldDefinitions`):

```
ERROR: Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input "{\n  id: ID! @id\n  name: String!\n  email: String! @unique\n  password: String!\n  resetToken: String\n  resetTokenExpiry: String\n  permissions: Permission[", expected ImplementsInterfaces, DirectivesConst or FieldDefinitions (line 10, column 11):
type User {
          ^

{
  "data": {
    "deploy": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 9
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "deploy"
      ],
      "code": 3017,
      "message": "Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input \"{\\n  id: ID! @id\\n  name: String!\\n  email: String! @unique\\n  password: String!\\n  resetToken: String\\n  resetTokenExpiry: String\\n  permissions: Permission[\", expected ImplementsInterfaces, DirectivesConst or FieldDefinitions (line 10, column 11):\ntype User {\n          ^",
      "requestId": "us1:ck6au2sum8frx0b00fviv1dom"
    }
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

I'm not sure what that error means, but I do have a feeling that it doesn't understand the `@unique` type modifier at the email field. It wasn't there previously and deploys worked fine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the strategy and @scalarList directive.

> This @scalarList(strategy: STRATEGY!) directive is required on any
>   scalar list field. The only valid argument for the strategy argument
>   is RELATION.

```
type Post {
  tags: [String!]! @scalarList(strategy: RELATION)
}
```

It is required for all scalar and enum list fields.

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MYSQL-knul/#@scalarlist

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! The documentation wasn't very direct with that requirement, and I had to re-read it again to figure that out.